# How to pick only those keys of a map, where values satisfy a condition?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Suppose, I have a map of PIPs:

```yaml
pips:
  dispy:    "4.9.1"
  psutil:   "latest"
  pyodbc:   "latest"
  foo:      "absent"
```

and wish to use the Ansible [pip-module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/pip_module.html) to install/upgrade/remove them.

How do I filter only those of names from the `pips`, where the value is set to `latest`?

*Update*: using the recipe by @techraf I was able to come up with the following:

```yaml
- name: Install PIPs by explicit versions
  pip:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    executable: "{{ pip }}"
    version: "{{ pips[item] }}"
  loop: >-
    {{ pips | dictsort | rejectattr(1, 'in', '["latest", "absent"]') | map('first') | list }}

- name: Upgrade or remove other PIPs as prescribed
  pip:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    executable: "{{ pip }}"
    state: "{{ pips[item] }}"
  loop: >-
    {{ pips | dictsort | selectattr(1, 'in', '["latest", "absent"]') | map('first') | list }}
```

Which works, but is unsatisfying -- because the original `pips`-map is turned into another object using `dictsort` and then again into a `list`. And each instance of the task still needs to look up the value (to set either the `version` or the `state` clause) to execute anyway...

There is got to be a better way...

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
{{ pips | dictsort | selectattr(1, 'equalto', 'latest') | map('first') | list }}
```

yields a list:

```
[
    "psutil",
    "pyodbc"
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there not anything better? Each `|` creates a new objects, does not it? Only to reap it immediately afterwards...

Comment: No. `selecattr` and `map` are generators, that's why `list` is required.